# Emitting a warning for a deprecated Swift protocol method in implementing types

Tags: swift, swift3

Suppose I have a protocol with a `bar()` method that has a default implementation — essentially the Swift way of making a protocol requirement optional for implementing types:

```
protocol Foo {
    func bar()
}

extension Foo {
    func bar() {
        print("default bar() implementaion")
    }
}
```

Now suppose that I decide to rename that method `barrrr()`, because more `r`s are better:

```
protocol Foo {
    func barrrr()
}

extension Foo {
    func barrrr() {
        print("default barrrr() implementaion")
    }
}
```

Existing code may still implement the method with the old name:

```
class Thinger: Foo {
    func bar() {
        print("custom bar() implementaion")
    }
}
```

This code thinks it’s customizing a `Foo` method, but it isn’t. Callers will look for `barrrr()`, and get the default implementation. Nobody calls `bar()`.

I would therefore like to generate a warning for types that implement `Foo` and have a `bar()` method. This does not work:

```
protocol Foo {
    func barrrr()

    @available(*, deprecated: 0.99, renamed: "barrrr()")
    func bar()
}

extension Foo {
    func barrrr() {
        print("default barrrr() implementaion")
    }

    func bar() {
        fatalError("renamed barrrr()")
    }
}

class Thinger: Foo {
    func bar() {   // No warning here!
        print("custom bar() implementaion")
    }
}
```

Making the extension method `final` has no effect. Is there a way to do it? It needn’t be a friendly warning; any compiler error would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I don't believe there is a way to do this--nor should there be.

You have a protocol, let's call it `MyProtocol`...

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myOldFunction()
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func myOldFunction() {
        print("doing my old things")
    }
}
```

And in a later release, you would like to rename a function within your protocol.

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func myOldFunction() // now deprecated
    func myNewFunction()
}
```

The primary problem with throwing a deprecation warning on any class which conforms to `MyProtocol` and implemented `myOldFunction()` is that there's nothing wrong with classes implementing functions and properties that are *not* part of *your* protocol.

These methods or properties might still be perfectly valid implementations used by other things that don't care about your protocol.

Consider that nothing would stop us from doing this:

```
protocol ViewControllerDeprecations {
    func viewDidLoad() // mark deprecated
    func viewWillAppear(Bool) // mark deprecated
    // etc., for all the life cycle methods
}

extension UIViewController: ViewControllerDeprecations {}
```

Now every `UIViewController` subclass everywhere in any app that contains the file with the above code has these silly deprecation warnings all over it just because *your* particular protocol no longer uses these methods.

Comment: You make a good point, but I think the need for this stands. Consider: (1) The “accidental conformance” problem also exists — with equally severe consequences — if a method conforms to the _current_ method name that will actually be called. (2) In the real, full example, the method in question uses a detailed name & module-specific types that make it extremely unlikely somebody would use that method signature and not intend protocol conformance.

Comment: The way to resolve the accidental conformance problem that you’ve raised would be for all methods that conform to a protocol to explicitly declare that they do so — something like `override` that names a specific protocol. If Swift did that, it would indeed solve this problem! IIRC, there was discussion of this on swift-evolution — `@provide(MyProtocol)` or some such — to avoid name collisions between protocols. Given that the language doesn’t do this (yet), however, I think the warning is a reasonable thing to ask for.

Comment: The correct thing to do today is to try extraordinarily hard to get the protocol right in the first place, then when that fails, remove the old from the protocol, add the new, and document it all extraordinarily well.  And to be clear... sometimes name collisions on protocols is fully intentional.

Comment: This — “try extraordinarily hard to get the protocol right in the first place, then when that fails, remove the old from the protocol, add the new, and document it all extraordinarily well” — is _exactly_ what I did that caused me to ask the question. Swift 3 naming convention changes are what prompted the rename.

Answer (score 1):

Without taking a position on whether it is a good thing, as suggested by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430237/504931), exactly what you are asking for is not possible at least in Swift 3.

However, as I pointed out [in response to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029146/504931), it is possible to deprecate an entire protocol, and doing so would at least give you deprecation warnings at the implementing type level, if not precisely at the wanted property / method level.

Comment: Doesn’t solve my particular problem, but a good option to remember about.